# Removal of container which uses a complex layout

Tags: java, swing, applet, gridbaglayout

I'm creating an (j)applet where the user has access to several different views selectable from a tree. The applet has a main area where the current view is displayed inside a scrollpane, replacing whatever was previously there. Most of the time this works fine, but when the view to be replaced has a more complicated layout, as in large (~100 components), not nested, the removal takes several seconds! Creation of the large view is lightning quick, only the removal is slow. This is only noticeable in applets, running the application in a JFrame is still as fast as I expect. I use GridBagLayout for the view.

After some experimentation, I found that if I replace

```
contents.remove(view); //contents is the view of the scrollpane.
```

with

```
view.removeAll();
contents.remove(view);
```

then the whole process is very fast.

My guess is that the cause of this behavior is some of Java's layout "magic", and although I have a solution it doesn't feel right and seems to indicate that I don't fully understand what's going on. So my question(s) is this:
Does someone know what's actually happening? Is there a better (clearer) way to accomplish the same thing?

Edit: SSCCE: http://pastebin.com/VC1T7zGv

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class SSCCE extends JApplet {
    private boolean state;

    public void init() {
        super.init();
        getContentPane().add(setupSwitchPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        getContentPane().add(setupSimplePanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private JPanel setupSwitchPanel() {
        JPanel switchPanel = new JPanel();
        switchPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Switch panels (slow)") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                switchComponents();
            }
        }));

        switchPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Switch panels (fast)") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                ((JPanel)getContentPane().getComponent(1)).removeAll();
                switchComponents();
            }
        }));
        return switchPanel;
    }

    private void switchComponents() {
        getContentPane().remove(1);
        if (state)
            getContentPane().add(setupSimplePanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        else
            getContentPane().add(setupComplexPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        state = !state;
        getContentPane().validate();
    }

    private JPanel setupComplexPanel() {
        JPanel contents = new JPanel();
        contents.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        for (int x = 0; x<10; x++) {
            c.gridx = x;
            for (int y = 0; y<10; y++) {
                c.gridy = y;
                contents.add(new JLabel(x + ", " + y), c);
            }
        }
        return contents;
    }

    private JPanel setupSimplePanel() {
        JPanel contents = new JPanel();
        contents.add(new JLabel("Simple view"));
        return contents;
    }
}
```

Comment: @AndrewThompson A CardLayout might work if I put the views in separate JScrollPanes, but I would prefer to not keep all of the different views in memory.

Comment: I decided to give it a try and this might work - I was actually expecting to get the same behavior. CardLayout may well be the most idiomatic solution as well. I'll probably go with this, but I'm still curious as to why removal of sub-components makes removal of the parent component quicker.

Comment: 1) I entered the comments as an alternate strategy. 2) Nice SSCCE +1 - I pasted it into the question as an edit.  3) Intriguing observation, but I'd tend to use the best layout & move on to some new challenge.  Hope you get a solution.  :)

Comment: I just ran the code from Eclipse and the slow/fast buttons seemed to both swap the UI very quickly.  Oh wait, Chrome shows the exact behavior you describe, there is a significant lag when changing the UI using the 'slow' button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate strategy: Use a `CardLayout`.

> I would prefer to not keep all of the different views in memory.

Why? The typical memory could allow the storage of hundreds of cards with hundreds of components.

Create them lazily and the GUI might only have 20-40 cards in a typical usage run. Of course, re-use existing cards for common tasks, just change the content.

Answer (score 2):

- don't `add / remove` something to the `JScrollPane` already visible, (sure you can to try to call [setViewportView(Component)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setViewportView%28java.awt.Component%29), but I don't suggest doing that)
- put father `JPanel` nested another `JPanel`s or `JComponent`s
- call father `JPanel#removeAll()`
- add a new `JPanel`s or `JComponent`s to the father  `JPanel`
- after that, make a call to the father `JPanel#revalidate()` and `JPanel#repaint()`

Comment: My bad, I'm actually not working with the JScrollPane directly but rather a JPanel which is set as the Viewport View. I'll edit my question as well.

Comment: JViewport is only visible Rectangle from JScrollPana, don't put something to that, your question isn't answerable without posting an SSCCE

Comment: The code is now edited into the question.  It is not till it is loaded in a browser that the problem is observable.

Answer (score 0):

In general, calling the "removeAll" of a component with many many children (consider for example a GridBagLayout with many rows) can be very slow because Swing fires a lot of notification events and calls several times synchronized sections (*java.awt.Component.getTreeLock()*).

A very useful tip is switching off visibility of the component **before** calling removeAll and turn it on again:

```
   mypanel.setVisible(false);
   mypanel.removeAll();  //<-- it can be very slow!!!
   mypanel.setVisible(true);
```

The removal of compoents which aren't visible is very fast.